# How should I use JUnit with Mockito to test to see if a method makes a method call to another Class?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I ran into a problem when I had to test a if else clause that only had method calls inside of them.

```
public CLI(String[] input){
    cliCheck(input);
}

public static void cliCheck(String[] input){
    if (input.length == 0) {
        System.out.println("No input");
        Help.help();
        System.exit(0);
    }
    if(input.length == 1){
        if(input[0] .equals("help") || input[0] == "-h") {
            Help.help();
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
    inputParser(input);
}
```

The code of from the beginning portion of a Command Line Interface program.

The first if is true when there is no input.
The second if is true when user types in "help" or "-h".
If not, then the input String is sent as the parameter of the inputParser method.

This is what I have so far...

```
@Test
public void cliCheckTest_Help(){    

    String[] input = {"help"};

    CLI cli = new CLI(input);

    Help help = mock(Help.class);
    cli.cliCheck(input);
    verify(help, times(1)).help();
}
```

(please tell me there is a better way to test for 100% branch coverage)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you created hard-to-test code here.

You see, that call to `System.exit()` will tear down your unit test in a very unpleasant manner.

You could do something like that instead:

```
public interface ShutdownService {
  public void systemExit();
}
```

and then create a "default" implementation that simply calls `System.exit()`.

But for your unit tests, you could instead "insert" a mocked version of that interface; and use that to verify that the expected call took place.

Beyond that, your code is also doing other things that make testing much harder than necessary - starting with the fact that you have **static** methods there; which then use a **static field** `inputParser`.

Long story short: **static** might look convenient, but it very much kills your ability to write reasonable unit tests.

So, my advise: learn how to create **testable** code; for example by watching these [videos](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLD0011D00849E1B79). And then improve the design of your *production code*. Because then you will find that writing tests becomes much easier!

And beyond that: **reasonable** handling of command line options is **much more** complicated than your naive implementation here. Unless this is for learning purposes: do **not** re-invent the wheel. There are libraries out there that do this kind of work for you. Use one of them!